# SparkContext object has no attribute esRDD (elasticsearch-spark connector)

Tags: apache-spark, elasticsearch, pyspark

In the spark-shell, I used with success the elasticsearch-hadoop connector (specifically the one developped for spark : elasticsearch-spark-20_2.11-5.1.2.jar). Invoking spark:

```
] $SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-shell --master local[2] --jars ~/spark/jars/elasticsearch-spark-20_2.11-5.1.2.jar
```

In the scala shell:

```
scala> import org.elasticsearch.spark._
scala> val es_rdd = sc.esRDD("myindex/mytype",query="myquery")
```

It perfectly works. I want to do the same with pyspark. I tried:

```
] $SPARK_HOME/bin/pyspark --master local[2] --driver-class-path=/home/pat/spark/jars/elasticsearch-spark-20_2.11-5.1.2.jar
```

but in the python shell, call to esRDD method is not possible:

```
>>> sc.esRDD
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  AttributeError: 'SparkContext' object has no attribute 'esRDD'
```

jar library was loaded because this call works:

```
>>> conf = {"es.resource" : "myindex/mytype", "es.nodes" : "localhost"}
>>> rdd = sc.newAPIHadoopRDD("org.elasticsearch.hadoop.mr.EsInputFormat","org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable","org.elasticsearch.hadoop.mr.LinkedMapWritable", conf=conf)
```

Does someone know how to use esRDD() in pyspark?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`esRDD` doesn't exist in `pyspark` actually.

Thus it will only work in spark **scala** and you need to import the following :

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._

import org.elasticsearch.spark._
```

Now you can read data :

```
val rdd = sc.esRDD("index_name/doc_type")
```

Comment: Any of these imports results in: ImportError: No module named ... Note that I'm in python shell, not in scala one (ref. your val rdd command)

Comment: In pyspark, I import the context with: from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext

Comment: Oh sorry considering your two other questions, I thought you were working python. let me fix this

Comment: it seems like it doesn't exist in pyspark

Comment: That was my feeling too. Little bit strange, isn't it?

Comment: Yes it is but you can always patch it

Comment: Sorry but what do you mean by "patch it"?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134843/discussion-between-eliasah-and-patrick).